# Flutter: There is a way to pick a random const from the consts defined in a Class?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to defined some 'custom' enum colours. As Flutter don't support custom enumerators, I went to Flutter source to see how they where doing for `Color`, and I made mine in the same way:

```
class SkinColors {
  // This class is not meant to be instantiated or extended; this constructor
  // prevents instantiation and extension.
  // ignore: unused_element
  SkinColors._();

  static const Color tanned = Color(0xFFFD9841);
  static const Color yellow = Color(0xFFF9D562);
  static const Color pale = Color(0xFFFFDBB4);
  static const Color light = Color(0xFFEDB98A);
  static const Color brown = Color(0xFFD08B5B);
  static const Color darkBrown = Color(0xFFAE5D29);
  static const Color black = Color(0xFF614335);
}
```

Now, I wanted to pick a random color from this list. I went again to `material/colors.dart`, I checked what they did with `primaries` and I did something similar. I added this code to my class:

```
  static const List<Color> colors = <Color>[
    tanned,
    yellow,
    pale,
    light,
    brown,
    darkBrown,
    black,
  ];

  static random() => colors[Random().nextInt(colors.length)];
```

But, I don't like this way of doing that because I have duplicated information and every time I add a new color, I have to remember to add it to the `colors` List.

Is there another approach to get a random constant from the constants defined in a Class?

I have another 'normal' enums like:

```
enum SkinType {
  dry,
  oily,
  sensitive,
}
```

I prefer that the user does not need to know whether he/she is using an enum or a class and can use all of them in the same way.

So I prefer one approach where you can use:

```
   var mySkin=SkinType.dry;
   var mySkinColor=SkinColor.tanned;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution with a `DelegatingMap`

Here is another solution using a `DelegatingMap`.

[image]

`SkinColor` is defined as:

```
class SkinColor extends DelegatingMap<String, Color> {
  static const Map<String, Color> colors = {
    'tanned': Color(0xFFFD9841),
    'yellow': Color(0xFFF9D562),
    'pale': Color(0xFFFFDBB4),
    'light': Color(0xFFEDB98A),
    'brown': Color(0xFFD08B5B),
    'darkBrown': Color(0xFFAE5D29),
    'black': Color(0xFF614335),
  };

  Map<String, Color> get delegate => colors;

  static Color get random {
    return colors.values.elementAt(Random().nextInt(colors.values.length));
  }
}
```

And the usage is pretty basic:

```dart
SkinColor.colors; // List of all Colors as a `Map<String, Color>`
SkinColor()['tanned']; // A specific skin `Color`
SkinColor.random; // A random `Color`
```

### Full source code

```
import 'dart:math' show Random;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _selected = useState(SkinColor.random);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            color: _selected.value,
            child: DropdownButtonFormField<Color>(
              items: SkinColor.colors
                  .map((name, color) {
                    return MapEntry(
                        name,
                        DropdownMenuItem<Color>(
                          value: color,
                          child: Text(name),
                        ));
                  })
                  .values
                  .toList(),
              value: _selected.value,
              onChanged: (newValue) => _selected.value = newValue,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 2.0),
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 5,
              childAspectRatio: 1,
              mainAxisSpacing: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 2,
              children: List.generate(
                50,
                (_) => ColoredBox(color: SkinColor.random),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SkinColor extends DelegatingMap<String, Color> {
  static const Map<String, Color> colors = {
    'tanned': Color(0xFFFD9841),
    'yellow': Color(0xFFF9D562),
    'pale': Color(0xFFFFDBB4),
    'light': Color(0xFFEDB98A),
    'brown': Color(0xFFD08B5B),
    'darkBrown': Color(0xFFAE5D29),
    'black': Color(0xFF614335),
  };

  Map<String, Color> get delegate => colors;

  static Color get random {
    return colors.values.elementAt(Random().nextInt(colors.values.length));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, such a very complete answer!!!

But I think that I can't do something like `var mySkinColor=SkinColor.tanned;`

Is there something like `magic PHP __get()` methods in dart? (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) Because then, I could make a magic `__get()` method that returns `SkinColor()['tanned'];`

Comment: I have a good and a very bad news for you. The good news is that yes, it exists, in `dart:mirrors`. But the very bad news is that it will not work on Flutter. You might find some package that would emulate reflection ahead of time though. Have a look at `reflectable`. Though, I personally never used it.

Comment: Thank you for gime more options. As I see, there's not one easy way to do what I was looking for. But I really appreciate the options that you give me.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution with an `enum`.

Here below, I define a `SkinColor` enumeration. Then, thanks to a Dart `extension`, I define the color code of each `SkinColor` value as a map, as well as a `Color getter`.

I also add a `static SkinColor get random` that you may access from the `extension`. This gives you a random `SkinColor`.

```
import 'dart:math' show Random;
import 'dart:ui' show Color;

void main() {
  SkinColor randomSkinColor = SkinColor.values[Random().nextInt(SkinColor.values.length)];
  print(randomSkinColor.color);
  
  randomSkinColor = SkinColorX.random;
  print(randomSkinColor.color);
}

enum SkinColor  {
  tanned,
  yellow,
  pale,
  light,
  brown,
  darkBrown,
  black,
}

extension SkinColorX on SkinColor {

  static const colors = {
    SkinColor.tanned : Color(0xFFFD9841),
    SkinColor.yellow : Color(0xFFF9D562),
    SkinColor.pale : Color(0xFFFFDBB4),
    SkinColor.light : Color(0xFFEDB98A),
    SkinColor.brown : Color(0xFFD08B5B),
    SkinColor.darkBrown : Color(0xFFAE5D29),
    SkinColor.black : Color(0xFF614335),
  };

  Color get color => colors[this];
  
  static SkinColor get random => SkinColor.values[Random().nextInt(SkinColor.values.length)];
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like your approach, it's a good one and I didn't know about extensions. But, just for this case, you are also duplicating the skin colours in two places (like in my approach) and I want to find a way so when I add a new colour, I have to add only on one place. At the same time, I will prefer to use `var mySkinColor=SkinColor.light` and with your approach, I have to use `mySkinColor=SkinColor.light.color`. (I updated my question about that)